# jQuery AJAX returned result

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having an issue with an ajax call using jQuery.  I am posting information to the server, and getting back data as expected.  The type of data I am getting back is html.  Using firebug, if I console.log the data, it shows an object with all my tags.  I want to manipulate the form of the returned data, but when I try to console.log the form, I get an empty object.  What am I doing wrong?  Here is my code:

```
$.post('add', {'ajax':true}, function(data){  
  var $data = $(data);  
  console.log($data.find('form'));  
});
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, nothing seems wrong.  Could you post the response?

Comment: It's kind of difficult to post the response.  If I console.log the data without wrapping it in a jQuery object, I get back an <h3>, <p>, <form> and all associated tags in the <form>.

Comment: if i console.log with the data wrapped in a jQuery object, I get in the console:

+ [h3, <TextNode>, p.required, <TextNode>, form#formAdd add]

I'm trying to grab that form

Comment: by the way, my version of jQuery is 1.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/57fek/). It works as expected. Maybe your response is not good?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a bad response.  I tried the example in my code, and I get back an empty string.  But again, if I don't wrap the data in a jQuery object, the response I get back is html

Comment: I meant something other than HTML. Can you show the page url, so we can see it?

Comment: unfortunately, that's not possible

Comment: basically, here is what I am getting back as html
<h3>...</h3>
<p>...</p>
<form>...</form>

Comment: I'm not requesting a full html document.  For instance, I don't get an <html>, <body> or anything like that back, because I am not sending it on the server side.  could that be the problem?

Comment: ok I think I know what's wrong, compare [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/57fek/3/) to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/57fek/4/), what you need is an element that is a single parent of all your html

Comment: I think it's because a proper XML document can only have one "top level" element. This is why html has a `<html>` enclosing the whole thing

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer the following syntax for selecting elements out of an HTML response:

```
$.post('add', {'ajax':true}, function(data){
  var myform = $('form', data); 
  console.log(myform);  
});
```

The second argument to the `$()` method is used as the context in which to search.

Comment: I tried this and I still get 'undefined' under "context" in firebug.  Under "selector" it does give me 'form', but if I try to alert something like myform.attr('id') id get 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
var $data = $(data);
```

If you remove it, you will have the html code returned by server as a normal string variable inside data.

Comment: but then how do I grab the form element?